# Need Help in JSON to retrieve data in certain way

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have data in format:

```js
{
  "name": "live",
  "description": " ",
  "aapUuId": "dsdfasds-dsdasa-asdasdsa",
  "backbutton": "10",
  "mainbutton": "10",
  "appInfo": {
    "items": [
      {
        "menuContent": "To continue now",
        "menuOrder": 1,
        "itemType": "static",
        "requestURL": "",
        "screen": {
          "items": [
            {
              "menuContent": "Yes",
              "menuOrder": 1,
              "itemType": "static",
              "requestURL": "",
              "screen": {
                "items": [
                  {
                    "menuContent": "Yes",
                    "menuOrder": 1,
                    "itemType": "static",
                    "requestURL": "",
                    "screen": {
                      "items": [
                        {
                          "menuContent": "Yes",
                          "menuOrder": 1,
                          "itemType": "static",
                          "requestURL": "",
                          "screen": {
                            "items": [
                              {
                                "menuContent": "Thank You",
                                "menuOrder": 0,
                                "itemType": "input",
                                "requestURL": "",
                                "screen": {

                                },
                                "link": ""
                              }
                            ],
                            "menuId": "1_1_1_1_1",
                            "menuHeader": "",
                            "menuFooter": ""
                          },
                          "link": ""
                        },
                        {
                          "menuContent": "No",
                          "menuOrder": 2,
                          "itemType": "static",
                          "requestURL": "",
                          "screen": {

                          },
                          "link": "1_1_1_1_1"
                        },
                        {
                          "menuContent": "Can't Say",
                          "menuOrder": 3,
                          "itemType": "static",
                          "requestURL": "",
                          "screen": {

                          },
                          "link": "1_1_1_1_1"
                        }
                      ],
                      "menuId": "1_1_1_1",
                      "menuHeader": "Are you satisfied with the condition of water supply in your area?",
                      "menuFooter": ""
                    },
                    "link": ""
                  },
                  {
                    "menuContent": "No",
                    "menuOrder": 2,
                    "itemType": "static",
                    "requestURL": "",
                    "screen": {

                    },
                    "link": "1_1_1_1"
                  },
                  {
                    "menuContent": "Can't Say",
                    "menuOrder": 3,
                    "itemType": "static",
                    "requestURL": "",
                    "screen": {

                    },
                    "link": "1_1_1_1"
                  }
                ],
                "menuId": "1_1_1",
                "menuHeader": "Are you satisfied with the condition of roads in your area?",
                "menuFooter": ""
              },
              "link": ""
            },
            {
              "menuContent": "No",
              "menuOrder": 2,
              "itemType": "static",
              "requestURL": "",
              "screen": {

              },
              "link": "1_1_1"
            },
            {
              "menuContent": "Can't Say",
              "menuOrder": 3,
              "itemType": "static",
              "requestURL": "",
              "screen": {

              },
              "link": "1_1_1"
            }
          ],
          "menuId": "1_1",
          "menuHeader": "Are you satisfied with the state of cleanliness in your area?",
          "menuFooter": ""
        },
        "link": ""
      },
      {
        "menuContent": "To participate later",
        "menuOrder": 2,
        "itemType": "static",
        "requestURL": "",
        "screen": {
          "items": [
            {
              "menuContent": "Today",
              "menuOrder": 1,
              "itemType": "static",
              "requestURL": "",
              "screen": {

              },
              "link": "1_1_1_1_1"
            },
            {
              "menuContent": "Tomorrow",
              "menuOrder": 2,
              "itemType": "static",
              "requestURL": "",
              "screen": {

              },
              "link": "1_1_1_1_1"
            },
            {
              "menuContent": "Day after Tomorrow",
              "menuOrder": 3,
              "itemType": "static",
              "requestURL": "",
              "screen": {

              },
              "link": "1_1_1_1_1"
            },
            {
              "menuContent": "During weekend",
              "menuOrder": 4,
              "itemType": "static",
              "requestURL": "",
              "screen": {

              },
              "link": "1_1_1_1_1"
            },
            {
              "menuContent": "Next Week",
              "menuOrder": 5,
              "itemType": "static",
              "requestURL": "",
              "screen": {

              },
              "link": "1_1_1_1_1"
            }
          ],
          "menuId": "1_2",
          "menuHeader": "Please confirm the suitable date when you wish to take the survey",
          "menuFooter": ""
        },
        "link": ""
      },
      {
        "menuContent": "Don't want to participate",
        "menuOrder": 3,
        "itemType": "static",
        "requestURL": "",
        "screen": {

        },
        "link": "1_1_1_1_1"
      }
    ],
    "menuId": "1",
    "menuHeader": "Welcome to DoIT Reality Check Survey!",
    "menuFooter": ""
  }
}
```

I need to get data out of it in certain format.

If json['link'] is not available then 
  simply print menu header and items

but if link is mentioned link 1_1_1 then go to that menu id 1_1_1 and 
print menu header and items.

js or php any way.

i tried this in php.

```php
function saving_for_app($finalAppData,$appid)
    {

        //Rest will be done tommorow follow dashboard/hitme
        $json = json_decode($finalAppData, true); // decode the JSON into an associative array

        $header = $json['appInfo']['menuHeader'];

        $data = array(
            'menu' => $header ,
            'app_id'=> $appid ,
            'master_id'=>0,
            'type'=>'Static',
            'menu_level'=>1,
            'menu_type'=>'0'
        );  ///// 1

        $this->db->insert('tbl_menu', $data);

        $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();

        foreach ($json['appInfo']['items'] as $item) 
        {                    

              $data1 = array(
                    'menu' => $item['menuContent'],
                    'app_id'=> $appid ,
                    'master_id'=>$insert_id,
                    'type'=>'Static',
                    'menu_level'=>0,
                    'menu_type'=>'1'

              );
              $this->db->insert('tbl_menu', $data1);

              $insert_id1 = $this->db->insert_id();

              // 1 ke option 
              $linkstatus = $item['link'];

              //rolling link

              $header1 =  $item['screen']['menuHeader'];

              $data = array(
                    'menu' =>$header1,
                    'app_id'=> $appid,
                    'master_id'=>$insert_id1,
                    'type'=>'Static',
                    'menu_level'=>2,
                    'menu_type'=>'0'
               );

              $this->db->insert('tbl_menu', $data);
              $insert_id2 = $this->db->insert_id();

              foreach ($item['screen']['items'] as $item1) 
              {                      

                    $data1 = array(
                        'menu' => $item1['menuContent'],
                        'app_id'=> $appid ,
                        'master_id'=>$insert_id2,
                        'type'=>'Static',
                        'menu_level'=>0,
                        'menu_type'=>'1'
                    );
                    $this->db->insert('tbl_menu', $data1);

                    $linkstatus = $item1['link'];

                    //rolling link

                    $insert_idx1 = $this->db->insert_id();                        

                    $header1x =  $item1['screen']['menuHeader'];

                    $data = array(
                          'menu' =>$header1x,
                          'app_id'=> $appid,
                          'master_id'=>$insert_idx1,
                          'type'=>'Static',
                          'menu_level'=>3,
                          'menu_type'=>'0'
                     );

                    $this->db->insert('tbl_menu', $data);
                    $insert_id2x = $this->db->insert_id();

                    foreach ($item1['screen']['items'] as $item2) 
                    {


                          $data1 = array(
                              'menu' => $item2['menuContent'],
                              'app_id'=> $appid ,
                              'master_id'=>$insert_id2x,
                              'type'=>'Static',
                              'menu_level'=>0,
                              'menu_type'=>'1'
                          );
                          $this->db->insert('tbl_menu', $data1);

                          $insert_idx2 = $this->db->insert_id();

                          $linkstatus = $item2['link'];

                          //rolling link


                          $header2x =  $item2['screen']['menuHeader'];

                          $data = array(
                                'menu' =>$header2x,
                                'app_id'=> $appid,
                                'master_id'=>$insert_idx2,
                                'type'=>'Static',
                                'menu_level'=>4,
                                'menu_type'=>'0'
                           );

                          $this->db->insert('tbl_menu', $data);
                          $insert_id3 = $this->db->insert_id();


                          foreach ($item2['screen']['items'] as $item3) 
                          {


                                  $data1 = array(
                                      'menu' => $item3['menuContent'],
                                      'app_id'=> $appid ,
                                      'master_id'=>$insert_id3,
                                      'type'=>'Static',
                                      'menu_level'=>0,
                                      'menu_type'=>'1'
                                  );
                                  $this->db->insert('tbl_menu', $data1);

                                  $insert_idx3 = $this->db->insert_id();

                                  $linkstatus = $item3['link'];

                                  //rolling link

                                  $header3x =  $item3['screen']['menuHeader'];

                                  $data = array(
                                        'menu' =>$header3x,
                                        'app_id'=> $appid,
                                        'master_id'=>$insert_idx3,
                                        'type'=>'Static',
                                        'menu_level'=>5,
                                        'menu_type'=>'0'
                                   );

                                  $this->db->insert('tbl_menu', $data);
                                  $insert_id5 = $this->db->insert_id();


                                    foreach ($item3['screen']['items'] as $item4) 
                                    {


                                          $data1 = array(
                                              'menu' => $item4['menuContent'],
                                              'app_id'=> $appid ,
                                              'master_id'=>$insert_id5,
                                              'type'=>'Static',
                                              'menu_level'=>0,
                                              'menu_type'=>'1'
                                          );
                                          $this->db->insert('tbl_menu', $data1);

                                          $insert_idx4 = $this->db->insert_id();


                                          $linkstatus = $item4['link'];

                                          //rolling link                                             

                                          $header4x =  $item4['screen']['menuHeader'];

                                          $data = array(
                                                'menu' =>$header4x,
                                                'app_id'=> $appid,
                                                'master_id'=>$insert_idx4,
                                                'type'=>'Static',
                                                'menu_level'=>6,
                                                'menu_type'=>'0'
                                           );

                                          $this->db->insert('tbl_menu', $data);
                                          $insert_id6 = $this->db->insert_id();




                                    }



                            }



                    }





              }


        }


    }
```

But in this way i m missing link id. and multiple foreach loops that are pretty confusing.please help .any advice or suggestion to do this.

Comment: You should reduce the code here to the minimum needed where the problem is concerned.

Comment: Json is showing level like menu->submenu->sub-submenu and so on.

Comment: foreach item here if link is not available then simply print menu header and items and if link is availble then go to that level(menu id) and get header and items out.

Comment: From what I can see is that you may find it helpful if you would create a recursive method or function for this. Your loops seem exactly the same...

Comment: I hope everybody has understood my question.