# Use php variable index for retriving data from json

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, concatenation, codeigniter-2

This is my [json](http://jsfiddle.net/6gh9cwxz/).

In php

```
$json = json_decode($finalAppData, true); // decode the JSON into an associative array


//suppose this is $link = ['appInfo']['items'][0]['screen']['items'][0]['screen']['items'][0];
```

This code is not working.

```
echo $json .$link."['screen']['menuHeader']";
```

produces output as

```
Array['appInfo']['items'][0]['screen']['items'][0]['screen']['items'][0]['screen']['menuHeader'].
```

but i want text value that can be seen if i use simply

```
echo $json['appInfo']['items'][0]['screen']['items'][0]['screen']['items'][0]['screen']['menuHeader'];
```

How can use index which is stored in variable to output data from json in php.

Comment: Part-1 : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29146051/need-help-in-json-to-retrieve-data-in-certain-way

Answer (score 1):

This should be similar to what you want:

```
$json = json_decode($finalAppData, true); 

$link = "['appInfo']['items'][0]['screen']['items'][0]['screen']['items'][0]";

# Method #1
eval("echo \$json${link}['screen']['menuHeader'];");

# Method #2
$item = "\$json${link}";
eval("echo ${item}['screen']['menuHeader'];");
```

[eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) takes a string of PHP code and interprets it. In this case, the nested keys are stored as a string in `$link` and then concatenated with a string that will be interpreted into the `$json` array resulting in a string of PHP code that will be sent to `eval()` to be interpreted.

Comment: when you echo $link, you get this ['appInfo']['items'][0]['screen']['items'][0]['screen']['items'][0]   
i want $json with $link with "['screen']['menuHeader']" to output result not simply array.

Comment: Ah, okay, I think I understand a bit more now.

Comment: I updated the solution above based on your clarification. It now takes the `$json` variable, `$link` variable, and `['string']['menuHeader']` string.

Comment: @Grokify-Thank u thanks a lot. please upvote the question if that was challenging one.

Comment: @Grokify- is there any way i can put this value in a variable $item = "\$json${link}"; and use it like $item['screen']['menuHeader'];

Comment: I added "Method $2" above to handle `$item = "\$json${link};"`. Does that work for you?

Comment: why is it necessary to use eval every time ?

Comment: If the explanation on eval helps, please accept the answer again. It changes every time the answer is updated. I'll take a look at jsfiddle too.